# SQL injection in stored procedures and JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, json-extract

I am working on an API in Node/JavaScript with a MySQL database. I think this is a question not related to Node/JavaScript, just SQL, but I'm not sure about that.

Here I have a minimal example. Lets say I have a stored procedure to create an user:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS users_create;
CREATE PROCEDURE users_create(
  IN user JSON
)
BEGIN
  -- Retrieve values from JSON
  SET @name = JSON_EXTRACT(user, '$.name');
  SET @email = JSON_EXTRACT(user, '$.email');
  SET @password = JSON_EXTRACT(user, '$.password');
  SET @uuid = uuid();

  -- Insert new user
  INSERT INTO user (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (
    @uuid,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(@name),
    JSON_UNQUOTE(@email),
    JSON_UNQUOTE(@password)
  );

  -- Retrieve created user
  SELECT `id`, `name`, `email`, `status`, `createdAt` FROM user
  WHERE id = @uuid;

END
```

Now I have a new user object —Javascript—:

```
const newUser = {
  name: "This is me",
  email: "me@example.com",
  password: "strong_password",
}
```

And I call the procedure:

```
const createUserQuery = `CALL users_create('${JSON.stringify(newUser)}')`;
```

My question is: given that I'm using JSON to pass the data, and I'm using `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_UNQUOTE`, am I prone to SQL injection here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not prone to SQL injection.  You might have other problems with the code.  And your code might be unsafe if -- say -- the password is not encrypted.

However, the only SQL code that will run is the SQL in the stored procedure.

SQL injection is associated with *dynamic* SQL.  That is SQL that is constructed from a string.  A SQL injection account alters ("enhances"?) the string to do dangerous things.  Your code is just assigning values in an `insert`.  These might be wrong, but they will not cause any other statements to run.

Comment: Interesting.  Reading [this](https://dev.to/hady_eslam/sql-injection-inside-stored-procedures-2db2) I just found out that, as my procedures are formatted, is not possible to remove the closing parentheses commenting them out with `--`. So I suppose that SQL injection needs an inlined string to attack SQL.
Also,